# Alarm clock not working on my tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Im trying to make a tkinter GUI with an alarm clock and weather. My alarm clock is not working for some reason. I "borrowed" the code from another person and it works on his/her program for some reason but not mine.

I haven't tried anything because im very new to python and coding in general.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os
import time
from time import strftime
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500


def test_function(entry):
    label3 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white',font=('Courier',15), text=entry, anchor='nw', justify='left', bd=4)
    label3.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


root = tk.Tk()

def quit_function():
    root.destroy()

def SubmitButton():
    AlarmTime= alarm_entry.get()
    CurrentTime= time.strftime("%H:%M")
    while AlarmTime != CurrentTime:
        CurrentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        time.sleep(1)
    if AlarmTime == CurrentTime:
        label3 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white',font=('Courier',15), text="Perkele", anchor='nw', justify='left', bd=4)


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='landscape.png')
bg_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#08AEF6', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.125, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

button = tk.Button(frame, font=40, text="Get Weather", bg='gray', fg='black', command=lambda: test_function(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relwidth=0.3, relheight=1)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#08AEF6', bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

up_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#08AEF6', bd=5)
up_frame.place(relx=0.675, rely=0, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

alarm_button = tk.Button(up_frame, text="Set alarm time", bg='gray', fg='black', font=40, command=SubmitButton)
alarm_button.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.45)

label3 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white')
label3.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
label = tk.Label(up_frame, bg='white')
label.place(relx=0, relwidth=0.695, relheight=0.5)

date1 = tk.Label(up_frame, bg='white', text=today, font=40)
date1.place(relx=0, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.695, relheight=0.5)

quit_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#08AEF6', bd=5)
quit_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.1)

quit_button = tk.Button(quit_frame, command=quit_function, text="Quit")
quit_button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

alarm_entry = tk.Entry(up_frame, font=40)
alarm_entry.insert(3, "esimerkiksi - 15:45")
alarm_entry.place(relx=0.7, rely=0, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.45)

# label2 = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white') 

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.focus_set()  


def time(): 
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
    label.config(text = string, font='40') 
    label.after(1000, time)

time()
```

It gives me this error in line 33.

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: You have a naming conflict between the function `time()` you define at the end of your code and the module `time` you are importing